# Select only one text at a time in div tag and change the color of selected text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a requirment where i should be able to select only one text at a time. As i select the text, background color of selected text should be changed. To achieve this i am using jquery. With the below code i am able to change the color of selected text,but i am not able to restrict it to only one selection at a given point of time.

$("#"+divid).find('.highlight').removeClass('.highlight');

$(val).addClass('highlight');

I am using the above two jquery codes to restrict to only one selection at a given point of time but its not working!

Please correct me if i have gone wrong anywhere!

Below snippet explains the problem more clearly!

```js
function check(val,divid){
$("#"+divid).find('.highlight').removeClass('.highlight');
$(val).addClass('highlight'); 
}
```

```css
.highlight{
background-color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="1">
<span id="a" onclick ="check(this,'1')">JAVA</span><br>
<span id="b" onclick ="check(this,'1')">ASP</span><br>
<span id="c" onclick ="check(this,'1')">C</span><br>
<span id="d" onclick ="check(this,'1')">C++</span><br>
</div>

<br>
<div id ="2">
<span id="e" onclick ="check(this,'2')">MATHS</span><br>
<span id="f" onclick ="check(this,'2')">ENGLISH</span><br>
<span id="g" onclick ="check(this,'2')">SOCIAL</span><br>
<span id="h" onclick ="check(this,'2')">SCIENCE</span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: change it to removeClass("highlight")  without the .

Answer (score 1):

Remove the period in front of `highlight` in the `removeClass` function.

```js
function check(val,divid){
$("#"+divid).find('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
$(val).addClass('highlight'); 
}
```

```css
.highlight{
background-color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="1">
<span id="a" onclick ="check(this,'1')">JAVA</span><br>
<span id="b" onclick ="check(this,'1')">ASP</span><br>
<span id="c" onclick ="check(this,'1')">C</span><br>
<span id="d" onclick ="check(this,'1')">C++</span><br>
</div>

<br>
<div id ="2">
<span id="e" onclick ="check(this,'2')">MATHS</span><br>
<span id="f" onclick ="check(this,'2')">ENGLISH</span><br>
<span id="g" onclick ="check(this,'2')">SOCIAL</span><br>
<span id="h" onclick ="check(this,'2')">SCIENCE</span><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot in `.removeClass()` is your issue. But if I could suggest you a better way to do what you want to do, it would be as below.

Forget about inline `onclick` attributes if you use jQuery... And use `.on()` to register your event handlers.

```js
$("span").on("click",function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight{
background-color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="1">
<span id="a">JAVA</span><br>
<span id="b">ASP</span><br>
<span id="c">C</span><br>
<span id="d">C++</span><br>
</div>

<br>
<div id ="2">
<span id="e">MATHS</span><br>
<span id="f">ENGLISH</span><br>
<span id="g">SOCIAL</span><br>
<span id="h">SCIENCE</span><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Louys Patrice Bessette was right and have give you a great example of how you can done it but i just want to provide my way of doing

But first you need to give all of them a class.
I prefered "skill"

this will work on both **div** seperately

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="1">
    <span id="a" class="skill">JAVA</span><br>
    <span id="b" class="skill">ASP</span><br>
    <span id="c" class="skill">C</span><br>
    <span id="d" class="skill">C++</span><br>
</div>

<br>
<div id ="2">
    <span id="e" class="skill">MATHS</span><br>
    <span id="f" class="skill">ENGLISH</span><br>
    <span id="g" class="skill">SOCIAL</span><br>
    <span id="h" class="skill">SCIENCE</span><br>
</div>



$('.skill').on('click',function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```